# Use a drawable in rate app dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a dialog pop up to rate my app and on this dialog is the android icon.

What i want is to be able to chose a drawable instead of the system icon like have my app icon in its place! this is my first time in using a rate app dialog so apologies if this is a basic question to you all as to me its a tough one, i think you should only need this one section of code where the icon is but if you require the full class then i can post that.

```
 builder.setMessage(message)
                .setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE)
                .setIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setCancelable(false)
```

Comment: If you don't want the app icon, then replace `context.getApplicationInfo().icon` with something else. You might want to show or explain in more detail what you want instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the `resource Id` of your app icon `drawable`, for example:

```
builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
            .setCancelable(false);
```

In this case `app_logo` can be `drawable` having your app icon.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for, had a feeling it would be something simple but again i have never done a rate dialog so could not resolve this without your help! much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can set icons with two ways:

Set the Drawable

```
AlertDialog.Builder setIcon (Drawable icon)
```

Set the resource id of the Drawable

```
  AlertDialog.Builder setIcon (int iconId)
```